# QT Creator - Adding Com Ports Dynamically To Menu Drop Down

Tags: qt, drop-down-menu, signals-slots

I am new to QT and am trying to add a list of available ports to a drop down menu. I am able to add the ports as actions to the menu but how do I dynamically wire it to a slot given that I don't know how many ports will be present?

```
//Populate drop down menus with available ports
for (QSerialPortInfo port : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
{
    //Grab available ports and add to menus
    ui->menuA500_Comm->addAction(port.portName());      

}
```

Comment: Cannot exactly understand the question. Do you want to determine what port is chosen in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

If menuA500_Comm is a QMenu, you can just add the SLOT like this:

```
ui->menuA500_Comm->addAction(port.portName(), this, SLOT(yourFunction()));
```

In this case every action will call the same function.

QMenu also has signals that you can connect, and then make different actions, depending on the Action that was triggered.

```
QObject::connect(ui->ui->menuA500_Comm, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(yourSlot(QAction*)));
```